# Is it possible to customize only the section and subsection numbers or titles in memoir?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, memoir

Like the question title says, is it possible to customize only the section and subsection numbers or titles in `memoir`? I know how to change the font for the entire block, but I would like to make the section numbers a bit smaller compared to the section title and to keep the subsection numbers upright while having the subsection title slanted.

Also, I would like to be able to do some stuff to the title without affecting the numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's sufficient to define suitably the "secnumformat"; its usual setup is

```
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

so we can modify in such a way that it executes different macros, for which I choose the names `\gablinsection`, `\gablinsubsection` and so on.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setsecnumformat{\csname gablin#1\endcsname\quad}
\newcommand{\gablinsection}{{\small\thesection}}
\newcommand{\gablinsubsection}{{\footnotesize\thesubsection}}
\newcommand{\gablinsubsubsection}{{\scriptsize\thesubsubsection}}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\section{Test me}
\subsection{Another test}
\subsubsection{Test me too}
\end{document}
```

The idea comes from [UK TUG FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-seccntfmt).

Comment: A much better idea!

Comment: That is a good idea

Answer (score 4):

You can define the `secnumformat` separately for each section level by adding a hook to the relevant sectioning command:

```
\headstyles{bringhurst}
% I don't know what style you're using but chose this one since it
% has italic subsection titles - the same principles apply to any 
% set of heading styles.
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
% Make sure subsections are numbered

\let\oldsection=\section
\let\oldsubsection=\subsection
% Save the existing sectioning commands

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{{%
  \setsecnumformat{\footnotesize\thesection\quad}%
  \oldsection{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{{%
  \setsecnumformat{{\upshape\thesubsection\quad}}%
  \oldsubsection{#1}}}
% New sectioning commands use \setsecnumformat to
% redefine the number font locally. Note the extra
% pair of curly brackets to make sure that the
% \secnumformat returns to normal after the (sub)section
% definition.
```

Then

```
\begin{document}
\section{Test me}
\subsection{Another test}
\subsubsection{Test me too}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: a set of headings with the required numbering fonts]

(the final `subsubsection` is to show that we haven't changed the numbering font globally).

(On a typographic note, though, it's possible that what you actually want for section numbers is not small numerals but "old style" ones - if they're available in the font you use.)

### Edit

@daleif has pointed out that the cunning extra groups have the unfortunate effect of breaking cross-references. An alternative that avoids this is

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldsection=\section
\let\oldsubsection=\subsection
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \let\oldsecnumformat=\@seccntformat%
  \setsecnumformat{{\footnotesize\thesection\quad}}%
  \oldsection{#1}%
  \let\@seccntformat=\oldsecnumformat}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{%
  \let\oldsecnumformat=\@seccntformat%
  \setsecnumformat{{\upshape\thesubsection\quad}}%
  \oldsubsection{#1}%
  \let\@seccntformat=\oldsecnumformat}
\makeatother
```

where, instead of defining a group within which the `secnumformat` is changed, the old format is explicitly saved and then restored, so that cross-references still work.

I note also that, if you don't care about restoring the old format (i.e., if you're happy to explicitly define a format for every section level you use) an easier method than the first one I showed would be

```
\setsechook{\setsecnumformat{{\footnotesize\thesection\quad}}}
\setsubsechook{\setsecnumformat{{\upshape\thesection\quad}}}
```

Comment: I'll add this to my todo list. But the solution above may have a side effect, it will break `\label` because the data `\label` use is locked inside the extra group

Comment: True! I guess the best thing to do in that case is explicitly save the old `secnumformat` and restore it afterwards. I'll edit to suggest this.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll lose all the facilities regarding optional arguments to `\section` and siblings.